# Update array React native

Tags: react-native, updates, draggable, react-native-flatlist

I try to update the name in my data array with the value I get from my selected name in my flatlist.

So here I select the name in my flatlist, If I print the selected name in the terminal it print out the selected name, so that works fine.

```js
const [name, setName] = useState();

<FlatList
  numColumns={1}
  horizontal={false}
  data={players}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
    <View>
      <PlayersListCard
        playersName={item.name}
        deleteIcon="add-circle-outline"
        click={() => {
          setModalVisiblePlayer(false), setName(item.name);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  )}
/>
```

And here I try to set the new value (name)

```js
const updateArray = (index) => (e) => {
  let newArr = [...data];
  newArr[index] = name;
  setData(newArr);
};
```

And here I try to print out the name in my draggable item (renderText)

```js
{
  data.map((item, key, index) => (
    <Draggable
      x={10}
      y={200}
      key={key}
      renderColor="blue"
      renderSize={50}
      onShortPressRelease={() => setModalVisiblePlayer(true)}
      isCircle
      textcolor="#000000"
      renderText={() => updateArray(index)}
      onDragRelease={(e) => {
        setItemPosition(key, e.nativeEvent.pageX, e.nativeEvent.pageY);
        console.log(item.X);
        console.log(item.Y);
      }}
    />
  ));
}
```

But their is something that I do wrong, can anyone see what?

Comment: use immer instead direct mutation.

Comment: Sample here is rather confusing, please consider adding a more complete and reproducible example. Where is setData defined, what component is `data.map` used etc?